# Emacs Lisp Error when called as command but works well when called as function

Tags: spacemacs, functions, commands

https://github.com/Cheatinikle/Spacemacs-settings/blob/master/emacs-package/preetest-mode.el

This is my full source code, and 'just-utils package is also included in the repository.

The problem is, when I open up a test (using preetest-open-test) and execute some function like preetest-next-question as a command, I get an error "No such directory found via CDPATH environment variable". However, when I run it with something like eval-last-sexp, it works well.

Comment: I presume you're unaware that most of `preetest-mode.el` is duplicated. Search for `(provide 'preetest)`.

Comment: If you provided an example 'test' file, people could try to replicate the issue.

Comment: 'test' file can be easily created with preetest-create-test, and my 'test' file has nothing special.

Comment: @phils
By the way, what do you mean by 'most of preetest-mode.el is duplicated'?

Comment: Please consider posting a self-contained question, with whatever code is necessary to repro your problem, and no more than that. If you just dump your entire config out there and ask people to debug it for you, you might not get the best help you need.

Comment: Is this the path problem with Emacs on OS X? Can you try [`exec-path-from-shell`](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell)?

Comment: @CheatiNikle Like I said, search for `(provide 'preetest)` -- everything from https://github.com/Cheatinikle/Spacemacs-settings/blob/master/emacs-package/preetest-mode.el#L254 onwards is duplicate code.

Comment: Well I tried running your code and using `preetest-create-test`, but there are calls to undefined functions like `select-window-1` and `select-window-2`, and the code throws errors if I delete those calls, so I stopped trying at that point. I suggest following Drew's suggestion.

Comment: select-window-1 is undefined? Well...

Comment: I think select-window-1 is Spacemacs function.

Comment: It's a small program so I left some duplicate codes which don't appear more than two times.

Comment: Oh. It really is duplicate. Sorry. Fixed it.

Comment: Please do not retitle the question "solved."  Post an answer with the solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
(defun preetest--update (n location)
  (with-directory location
    (select-window-2)
    (with-directory PREETEST-ANSWER-DIR
      (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
        (save-buffer)
        (unless (file-exists-p (number-to-string n)) (create-file (number-to-str    ing n)))
        (switch-to-buffer (find-file (number-to-string n)))
```

(kill-buffer buf)))

to

```
(defun preetest--update (n location)
  (with-directory location
    (select-window-2)
    (with-directory (concat location PREETEST-ANSWER-DIR)
      (let ((buf (current-buffer)))
        (save-buffer)
        (unless (file-exists-p (number-to-string n)) (create-file (number-to-str    ing n)))
        (switch-to-buffer (find-file (number-to-string n)))
```

(kill-buffer buf)))

and it worked.
I guess it was a directory reference problem.